# Laravel, tiene sentido hacer esta relacion morphable ? No lo tengo claro

Tags: laravel, polimorfismo

Partimos de 3 modelos: Servicios, productos y etiquetas.

Los dos primeros mencionados tendran etiquetas para ser ncontrados mas faciles, tengo 2 opciones en cuanto al backend:

1. hacer etiequetas_x_servicios y etiquetas_x_productos.
2. hacer la clase etiqueta morphable y me ahorro esas dos tablas.

¿Que duda me crea esto? Pues que una etiqueta por ejemplo este en ambos, ejemplo:

Pongamos que el usuario busca por la etiqueta `#blanco` en el buscador, esto podria devolver: un **producto** por ejemplo una taza que sea de color **blanco** , y tambien un **servicio** de limpieza que haya puesto que deja todo  **blanco** como etiqueta.

Entonces si es morphable las etiquetas y ocurre dicho caso, tendre repetido dos veces lo mismo pero con el `labelable_id` y `labelable_type` diferentes, es eso bueno ?

es decir, tendria dos veces la misma etiqueta guardada.

Aclaro: un producto/servicio podria tener n etiquetas.

Comment: Blanca no es lo mismo que blanco entonces no estaría duplicada la etiqueta

Comment: @BetaM he editado la pregunta, que pasaria en este neuvo caso ?

Comment: La segunda opción considero  no es viable pues sería mejor guardar solo la llave primaria de la etiqueta lo cual parece ser que requeriría que ETIQUETAS sea un modelo por separado y que `etiquetable` sea tal vez una tabla por separado pues de lo contrario con lo que planteas en la segunda opción estarías duplicando los nombres una y otra vez cuando solo deberías almacenar su referencia

Comment: Lo que buscas si es una relación polimórfica pero de muchos a muchos https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Answer (score 0):

No deberias tener ningun problema, yo considero que es el gran beneficio de crear una relacion de este tipo "Morph".

Lo unico que veo es que "si tienes un buscador" en tu front-end por "etiquetas", tienes que dejar claro (para tu usuario), en el mismo caso que tu propones, que un resultado es para servicio y el otro para producto, seria lo UNICO confuso que puedo ver.